# Annoying Pop-Up When Signing Onto Outlook-16

Tags: microsoft-outlook, user-accounts, migration

GoDaddy migrated my single-user email account from GD-Workspace to GD-Outlook365. After a month of failed support calls and unresolved tickets on the migration, I hired a MS partner to do second migration using a new GD domain.

2nd migration went fine. I have one residual problem that I can't seem to resolve. Would appreciate your thoughts.

Original domain was aaa.com and email was info@aaa.com.

New domain is bbb.com and email is info@bbb.com.

Problem is that every time I log in to Outlook-16, I get a pop-up that displays info@aaa.com and asks for my PW.

To log-in, I have to click the pop-up's option to "sign in with another account", type in info@bbb.com and enter that PW. Livable but annoying. Since I usually use the same laptop, would like to avoid pop-up at login altogether.

Any recommendations?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In Outlook, go to File > Account Settings > Account Settings.

Double-click on your email address and correct your username and password in that dialog.

**UPDATE**

First, if you download messages locally and have a PST, you'll need to find where this is:

In Outlook > File > Account Settings > Account Settings > Data Files find your PST file and click Open File Location...

Copy the PST file to a backup location in your files and then back in the Outlook Data Files window click Remove.

Close Outlook.

Open the Control Panel > Mail > Show Profiles > Add...

Create a new Profile and choose either Prompt for a profile to be used, or select the new profile as the one to be used when Outlook opens.

Open Outlook again and configure it with your current connection information.

Once the account is configured and is viewing new emails, go back to the Data Files window and click Add... and then find the PST file you moved earlier, attach it to Outlook, and make any other changes necessary to make sure it is the default PST for this account.

Once you've confirmed you have all the information in this new profile, you may delete the old profile.

Comment: Not sure this will work. Usually this kind of problem needs a new outlook profile.

Comment: Tried it. No effect.

Comment: There is only 1 email address in my account list: info@bbb.com.

Comment: Have no clue where residual info@aaa.com is coming from.

Comment: Then as @LPChip alludes, you need to create a new Outlook profile. Working on an edit now.

Comment: There's no need to download the email as PST, given that it is an exchange environment and the second migration was already succesful. Just creating a new outlook profile with the right login info should do the trick. Then once confirmed that it works, remove the old profile.

Comment: Also, exchange works with OST, not PST, so you can't make it the default for that account. IMAP, yes. Exchange, no.

Comment: Yes, but we're assuming he was on O365 before, and we're assuming he isn't archiving locally, which WOULD create a PST.